# Using two routers at home but prioritising one as the primary link

Tags: networking, router

I've looked for answers to this, but they seem cryptic or not applicable, but it is a fairly common question.

So here's the background : my domestic broadband is fast but flaky. I'd finally had enough of random days of not working, so I'm augmenting this with a Wireless unit. It has Ethernet (Netgear Nighthawk M2) with a 50Gb cap. We use far more than this monthly. No cap on the fixed line.

I obviously want to prioritise traffic onto the broadband. I'm running all the connections first through a Netgear Nighthawk R8000, then into a Virgin Media hub that's basically just a modem.

Is there a sane way to set this up to use both, or is it just better all round to stuff the hotspot unit in the cupboard until the next outage? Running my own DHCP/DNS/whatever else isn't a problem, but I'm aiming to improve reliability and get rid of the glitches in the single-line setup.

If I need to buy more hardware, not a problem. Happy to go with hardware if it's easier to maintain.

Comment: This us pretty advanced. In theory you could flash dd-wrt on your router (assuming there is only the 1 version if the R8000) and then use a process like https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dual_WAN_with_failover to handle fail over.

Comment: I have to disagree with David, this is a nightmare to setup on DD-WRT. You better become an expert with the crippled command prompt of DD-WRT, and iptables if you are heading this route... A better (and more stable) approach would be either Openwrt(w/Luci) or Pfsense as dedicated hardware. Both have built-in user friendly firewall/iptables & dual-wan settings in the web-ui.

Comment: DD-WRT looks too hard to setup and maintain. It is tempting to have total control but I'm shying away from writing scripts. I have doubts I'd be improving things, and a simple typo would be my undoing. The rest of the house depends on this broadband so it has to be stable.

Comment: I'll look into OpenWRT and Pfsense - I've not come across these before

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, you'd probably do best to buy one single dual-WAN router (it doesn't appear that yours is) and connect that to your cable and your LTE provider, and then set your failover rules appropriately. You can probably just get rid of your two existing routers.

Comment: So if I interpret this correctly: one cable modem, one LTE, a new dual-WAN router, and the R8000 for wireless? I don't think I can get rid of anything, just add the dual-WAN router?

Comment: You can find dual Wan routers that also have wifi, no need for an extra device unless your home layout requires it.